# Unable to validate iOS archive in Visual Studio, but uploads from XCode

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, upload, app-store

On Visual Studio Mac and Visual Studio Windows, when I attempt to upload my application to the App Store, I get a message during the upload process:

[image]

However, when I upload with XCode, there are no issues. I'm able to put the application into TestFlight, download to my phone and it runs fine:

[image]

How do I being to debug this problem?

Comment: There are many reasons for this error , like: missing APP icon, incorrect profile, doesn't increase the Build Version in info.plist... you can check the offical document to see if you miss something https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/?tabs=windows

Comment: Yes. I've checked all those reasons several times. None of those reasons fly if XCode can validate the package and upload it. What validation does Visual Studio do that XCode doesn't? How does a normal software engineer debug this issue without any feedback about what's wrong?

Comment: It seems that vs couldn't offter much information when uploads failed,you can post a feature request though https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home